# Get post data from custom_post_type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have created a custom post type named Books & i have a widget to access data from posts

i want to access data from regular posts & from Books

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => ???,
    'cat' => $category_id,
    'posts_per_page' => '6',
);
$new_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();
if(has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )):
?>
```

i use this code to access the posts data 
what need to be pass in 'post_type' to get data from Books & regular posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the post_type portion:

```
'post_type' => array('post','books'),
```